# Hold form of a function until its parameter is defined

Tags: function-construction

I'd like my function to evaluate only once it's parameter has been defined. If the parameter is undefined, I would like the function to hold until it becomes defined. As a trivial example, consider this function:

```
FirstPositionTrue[list_] := FirstPosition[list, True];
```

Evaluating this function with `FirstPositionTrue[{False, True, False}]` returns `{2}`, as expected.

I want `FirstPositionTrue[list] /. list->{False, True, False}` to return `{2}` as well. However, it instead returns `Missing["NotFound"]`. I think this is because `FirstPosition` evaluates on the empty symbol `list` *before* the substitution `list->{False, True, False}` takes place.

How could I make this function hold the evaluation of `FirstPosition[list, True]` until `list` is defined?

(I realise I could call `ReleaseHold[
 Hold[FirstPositionTrue[list]] /. list -> {False, True, False}]` and this would return `{2}` as expected. But I would rather not have to explicitly call `ReleaseHold` to evaluate the expression - I want `FirstPositionTrue[list] /. list->{False, True, False}` to suffice.)

Comment: `FirstPositionTrue[list_List] :=...`

Comment: Instead of futzing with `Hold[]`, just restrict the function's validity: `fpt[list_List] := FirstPosition[list, True]`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.